# mouse coordinate information at top of map with leaflet (mapview) in R

Tags: r, leaflet

the following example is taken from online help ?addMouseCoordinates

```
    library(mapview)
    library(leaflet)

    leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
    addMouseCoordinates(style = "basic") # with basic mouse position info

    leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
    addMouseCoordinates(style = "detailed") # with detailed mouse position info
```

I can't see any difference between detailed and basic style (at least in the viewer pane of RStudio)

even with

```
    leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
    addMouseCoordinates(style = "detailed",  epsg = "EPSG:32632", proj4string = "+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
```

I can't see any additional information other than lat, lon and zoom

my aim is to show in the box displaying the current cursor location the information of latitude and longitude but in a different crs, namely wgs84 / utm32 (cartesian coordinates)

is that possible?

do am I completely misinterpreting the help specifications?

Comment: Disclaimer: mapview developer here. Thanks for bringing this up. The way `addMouseCoordinates` works has changed but the examples were not updated. Sorry for that. There is now no more distinction between `style = "basic"` and `style = "detailed"`. To switch between the two, simply press and hold 'Ctrl' while moving the mouse and you will see the detailed version. Regarding the issue of displaying coordinates in UTM rather than longlat or webmercator, this is currently only possible when you create the map with mapview directly. As an example: `mapview(trails, native.crs = TRUE)`

Comment: Obviously this will only work without a basemap, as leaflet basemap tiles (and all provider tiles) are in crs 3857 - webmercator. The js leaflet library only provides access to the native 3857 or wgs84 (epsg:4326) coordinates but does not support any other crs when displaying basemaps. There is not really much we can do about this. If you want to be able to display detailed mouse position information also when not setting up the map via mapview but via leaflet, please open a feature request at https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues

Comment: thanks a lot for the specification, now it's clear